# URL to compose a message in Gmail (with GMAIL interface and including Attachment)

Tags: c#

I found an answer on this. Here is the link for open gmail in Gmail interface and passed parameters are To, Bcc, Subject and body : "https://mail.google.com/mail/?view=cm&fs=1&to=someone@example.com&su=SUBJECT&body=BODY&bcc=someone.else@example.com" but I want to pass the attachment as well. Can anybody tell me, How to pass attachment as a parameter in above link.?

Comment: Sadly, what you want to do isn't possible.